# Unusual memory leak in queue - code hangs on exit

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, queue

i need to create queue of classes to be processed by a thread afterwards. The problem is that every time i add a reference to an object, queue assigns memory for that class causing huge memory leaks. This also leads to program hang on exit.

Adding 12345678 references to an object of TaskClass to TaskQueue causes 137MB memory leak.
Notice that memory is not freed when calling queue.pop().

class TaskQueue:

```
template <class tjob>
class TaskQueue
{
private:
    std::queue<tjob> _taskqueue;
public:
    TaskQueue()
    {
        //constructor goes here
    }
    //add task to queue
    template < typename Class>
    bool AddTask( Class &PClass)
    {
        _taskqueue.push(PClass);
        return true;
    }
    bool ProcessQueue()
    {
        while (!_taskqueue.empty())
        {
            _taskqueue.front().run();
            _taskqueue.pop();
        }
        return true;
    }
    //run a function pointer
    template < typename Task >
    bool RunTask( Task task){
        task();
        return true;
    }
    //call class entry point member .run
    template < typename Class>
    bool RunClass ( Class& PClass){
        PClass.run();
        return true;
    }
    //return remaining tasks
    int GetRemainingTasks(){
        return _taskqueue.size();
    }
};
```

class TaskClass:

```
class TaskClass 
{
protected:
    int *ptr_x;
public:
    TaskClass() {
        std::cout << "TaskClass Constructor called\n";
        ptr_x = new int(0);
    }
    bool run(){
        *ptr_x = *ptr_x + 1;
        return true;
    }
    bool printx(){
        std::cout << "x is now " << *ptr_x << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
    ~TaskClass(){
        //std::cout << "TaskClass destructor called!\n";
    }
};
```

main:

```
int main()
{
    TaskClass job1;
    int nojobs = 12345678;
    TaskQueue<TaskClass> TestQueue;
    std::cout << "Preparing Queue... Adding " << nojobs << " tasks.. "; //std::cin.get();
    for (int i=0;i<nojobs;i++)
        TestQueue.AddTask(job1);
    std::cout << "Done!\n"; //std::cin.get();
    std::cout << "Processing Queue... "; 
    TestQueue.ProcessQueue();
    std::cout << "Done!\n"; 
    job1.printx();
    std::cout << "Remaining tasks: " << TestQueue.GetRemainingTasks() << std::endl;
    //std::cin.get(); 
    //exit(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have a new in TaskClass's constructor, but no delete in the destructor

Comment: you should run the code and notice that constructor only gets called once and destructor gets called nojobs times. so i delete that pointer if program will crash.

Comment: What about copy constructors? How are you counting them? Rule of 3 (or 5) (or 0)???

Comment: @DbS that's because you didn't implement a copy constructor. Why are you mucking around with templates and threads and dynamic memory before writing a simple class correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memory leak is

```
ptr_x = new int(0);
```

because you *never* delete that memory. At a minimum, you need to delete it in the destructor, and also add a copy constructor which deep-copies it.
A better solution is to replace the pointer with a simple

```
class TaskClass 
{
protected:
    int x;
```

(although I don't see why it would be `static` as in billz's answer).

---

Incidental infelicities:

1. unnecessary templating:

   ```
   template < typename Class>
   bool AddTask( Class &PClass) {
   ```

   the only valid type for `Class` is the class template argument `tjob`, so why template this method at all? And why require a non-const ref to something you can only copy?

   ```
   bool AddTask(tjob const &job) {
       _taskqueue.push(job);
       return true;
   }
   ```

   is better. Similarly for the other templated methods.
2. *i need to create queue of classes*

   No, you don't, and in fact you can't (I suppose you could create a queue of `typeinfo_t` if you really wanted). You need to create a queue of *objects*. Fortunately that's what you're actually doing, since calling an object reference `PClass` doesn't make it a pointer-to-class.

   This might seem (and indeed be) pedantic, but it's generally easier for everyone if you get the terminology right.